# Casting from a Type* to Type and vice versa

Tags: c++, types, casting

Is it possible to cast from a predefined Type_pointer in c++ to its Type?

For example we defined a custom XType.
I want to do something like this, but I get an error:

```
XType* b;    
XType a = (XType) b;
```

I want to pass the pointer itself to a function that only accept `Type` (not `Type*`)

Comment: do you want to _dereference_ the pointer? try `*b`.

Comment: Are you sure a cast is what you want?

Comment: I want to pass the pointer itself to a function that only accept Type (not Type*)

Comment: And do you want that function to access the pointed-to-object? Or some other object that you create?

Comment: Other functions then will use the "Type" args. They will have to cast it back to "Type*" to find the pointed-to area.

Comment: No, it won't work this way. When you are passing `Type`, you are passing a _copy_ of the object, so it's impossible to retrieve the address of the original object. You have to change the _function_ to take the pointer.

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks Vlad!

Comment: Can you please re-post it, So everybody else can see the answer clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the @Robᵩ's proposal, you can change the function to accept the pointer.

Actually, if you plan to pass the pointer to other functions from within the given function, you must get the pointer (well, or a reference) as parameter, otherwise you'll get a *copy* of the original object as the parameter, so you'll be unable to retrieve the address of (i.e. pointer to) the original object.

If you'd like to spare the refactoring, you can do the reference trick:

```
void g(T* pt)
{
    // ...
}

void f(T& rt) // was: void f(T rt)
{
    cout << rt.x << endl; // no need to change, syntax of ref access
                          // is the same as value access
    g(&rt); // here you get the pointer to the original t
}

T* t = new T();
f(t);
```

Comment: Robᵩ's solution is good. But not in my case. Because the *b has got a huge amount of data. That's why I want to pass the address between the functions not the data it refers to.

Comment: @Computer_guy: yes, in case of huge objects it's better to pass around pointers (or references).

Answer (score 2):

You should dereference the pointer with the `*` operator:

```
struct Type {
  Type(Type*) {}
};

void f(Type t) {
}

int main () {
  Type a;
  Type* b = &a;

  // Q: how to invoke f() if I only have b?
  // A: With the dereference operator
  f(*b);
}
```

Comment: I think Vlad gave the answer. I actually do not want to dereference the operator. I wanted to send its value (as an address) to different function. Vlad says it is impossible. Right! I had to think about it. Instead, I need to re-implement all the functions.

Comment: I'm glad you gained understanding, and that vlad was able to understand your true need. Please remember to accept vlad's answer (click the check-mark next to his answer.)